# How do you get request data to appear in the Developer Dashboard?

Tags: dashboard, developer

We are using SharePoint 2013 and trying to get the Developer Dashboard working in order to help diagnose performance bottlenecks. We've enabled the dashboard and can open it from the provided HTML button that appears, but no requests are showing up.

Within `Configure usage and health data collection` in Central Admin, we've checked `Enable usage data collection`. The ULS logs show Verbose entries that correspond to this usage data (e.g., "Entering monitored scope").

Are there specific events within `Configure usage and health data collection` that need to be logged? No matter what events I select, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated -- please let me know if you need more information.

[image: Dashboard Settings]

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: did you wait for 24 hours before this? i am not sure but this is how it usage work in 2010.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE is this due the `Log Collection Schedule` withing `Configure usage and health data collection`? That section states, "A time job collects log files from each server and copies events into a database that is used for reporting." Within that there is a job `Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import` that [appears](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870.aspx) to perform that task. This job is currently set to a 5-minute schedule.

Comment: check if the UsageApplication is connected to the Web App, from central admin > application management > click on web app and from ribbon service connection

Comment: Yes, we have a total of four web applications, and all four list `Usage and Health data collection (Type: Usage and Health Data Collection Proxy)` as an existing connection.

Comment: Can u share the screen shot of DD? Did you see any link on upper part when browse a site colletion?

Comment: Added a screenshot. It just always appears empty, as shown. When I have it open, page requests take a lot longer to load, but they eventually do. But no requests ever appear in the dashboard.

Comment: i got the same screen shot but after 5 min, it is working....what this command retruns get-spusageapplication?

Comment: get-spusageapplication returns one entry: Usage and Health with it's GUID. Can you tell me what events you're logging in `Configure usage and health data collection`? Do any settings within `Diagnostic Logging` matter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23923/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mcse-and-revengeoftheants).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the usage database?

Here is a pretty good blog post explaining Developer dashboard:
http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: Yes, we have the Usage database and the related service application and proxy are both running. As for articles and blog posts, I feel as if I've read them all -- I've definitely read this one several times. All of them suggest that it should just work if you have those services running and the dashboard is enabled.